# Grinding/streaking stutter when trying to start a 2006 deville. What is the cure for that? and can it be fixed immediatelyit be done immediately

Tags: starting, cadillac, deville

When I try to start my 2006 Cadillac deville, the starter seems like it is free spinning, and grinding on something causing, almost a screeching type of sound. Can that be fixed easily and immediately to start the car? Because that's all it does every time I try to start. Is there any other way I can start the automatic 2006 Cadillac deville?

Comment: Sounds like a failure of the bendix drive causing the starter to not engage with the flywheel.  If so, it is not a quick fix.

Comment: If your starter has a high pitched whine instead of the usual r-r-r sounds, its likely a damaged bendix drive on the starter  as Chenmunka mentioned and not repairable unless you're familiar with starter repairs. Even if intermittent, it's wiser to repair now than become stranded somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue here is that the starter is faulty and needs replacing.

One possible fault is that the starter pinion teeth have been damaged like in this [photo](https://www.handyhowie.co.uk/handyhowie/Spitfire_Starter_Motor.html) -

[image]

It may be that the mechanism on the starter motor that throws this pinon into the matching teeth on the flywheel is not working correctly.  This could be due to a seized bendix or a faulty solenoid mechanism.

There is also a very small chance that the starter motor mounting bolts have become loose so the pinion is no longer meeting the flywheel teeth correctly.

Finally, there may be a section of damaged teeth on the flywheel that the starter motor pinion meshes with.  This photo shows a section of good teeth on the flywheel viewed at the starter motor mounting location.

[image]

It is generally a relatively simple job to replace a starter motor.  It is best not to repeat the grinding of the teeth, since replacing the flywheel is a much bigger job and repeated grinding may damage the flywheel teeth.

If the issue is due to a damaged section of teeth on the flywheel, it may be possible to first turn the engine a little using a wrench on the front pulley, so that a good section of teeth meet the starter pinion when you try to start the engine.